Manchurian pear suckers - relocation
We have large established Manchurian pears throwing suckers. Can I remove and relocate Manchurian pear suckers?

As most pear (and apple) trees are grafted onto another rootstock, your suckers will not produce the flower show you want. I remove all suckers in most trees when they show.

Searching for it did not produce any definitive answers. The suckers are coming from the root. So there is a good chance that they will grow roots. Try to cut them as as far down as you can, so that they includey some branch/trunk from below ground level.
